# Saving bmp image multiple times on the same path C#

Tags: c#-2.0

So, I'm working on my paint application. Every time I make changes, the current screen state is copied and saved as a bitmap image on my disk (so I can use it in my paint event).

The problem occurs when I minimize and return the window to its normal state and then try to draw. This triggers my event reacting to changes, the program tries to save the image ---->>> kabooom.

It says "A generic error occurred in GDI+".. So, I've been surfing through various forums in search for the answer but none of them gave me true answer, they all mention wrong paths etc. but I'm pretty sure that's not the problem. Do I have to dispose bitmap or do something with the stream?

```
        int width = pictureBox1.Size.Width;
        int height = pictureBox1.Size.Height;

        Point labelOrigin = new Point(0, 0); // this is referencing the control
        Point screenOrigin = pictureBox1.PointToScreen(labelOrigin);

        int x = screenOrigin.X;
        int y = screenOrigin.Y;

        Rectangle bounds = this.Bounds;
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(x, y), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
            }
            bitmap.Save(_brojFormi + ".bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);                
        }
```

Comment: What is the value of `bounds.Size` when it goes kaboom?

Comment: From which line of code comes the error? Also, please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: bounds.Size is OK, nothing to worry there. The program crashes on bitmap.Save();
After resizing the form the picture redraws properly, but if I try to make changes after that it crashes..

Answer (score 0):

You're *saving an image to disk* so you can *use it in another event*? Wow.

Why not just use a class-global variable to store the bitmap?

```
class MyForm
{
    Bitmap currentImage = null;
    Graphics gfx = null;

    private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
        currentImage = new Bitmap(fileName);
        gfx = Graphics.FromImage(currentImage);
    }

    private void pbEditor_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentImage != null && gfx != null)
        {
             lock(currentImage) e.Graphics.DrawImage(currentImage, ...);
        }
    }

    private void pbEditor_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // quick example to show bitmap drawing
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            lock(currentImage) currentImage.SetPixel(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y, Colors.Black);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm saving every change on my form, that's what was important in that sentence. Every change is saved properly until I resize my form. Every next change after resizing causes crash. I could use a global variable, but I must store the picture on the disk anyway. The problem is saving it multiple times after resizing, globally or locally, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Yeah, the resize event will fire repeatedly - regardless of how long it takes to save the file. So you're probably saving, getting a new event before the save operation completes, then trying to save again. That'll cause the GDI+ error.

Comment: Also, you're doing a copy-from-screen during a form resize. If a user has draw-while-resizing switched off in their Windows theme profile, or if they're using remote desktop, you'll get a blank image (or a crash if the handle is invalidated).

Comment: Yup: `ResizeBegin` and `ResizeEnd`.

Comment: Saving is strictly done on mouse_up event (meaning drawing a shape is over) so resizing cannot be done at the same time as saving the image, resizing is not problem! My image redraws after bringing the window back to its normal state (all saves before resizing are done successfully).. Something happens with the path after resizing?!

Comment: I'd guess the save gets triggered when you bring the form back from being minimised. Regardless, this entire thing is very poorly designed - there's no reason to do CopyFromScreen, nor is there any reason to save to file constantly. It's bad for performance and, as you've discovered, causes a lot of headaches. Switch to a Bitmap as a variable, and draw to the screen using `graphics.DrawImage`.